# Reinventing std::optional

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

I decided to make my own version of C++17's [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

It's basically a class that can optionally hold a variable (as the name suggests), it avoids having to resort to `std::pair<bool, T>` to check whether a variable is set.

I'd like some feedback regarding the overall implementation

```
template<typename T>
class Optional {
 public:
  /**
   * The constructor
   */
  Optional() :
    is_set_(false) {}
  /**
   * The constructor
   * @param val The value to set it to
   */
  Optional(const T& val) :
    val_(val), is_set_(true) {}

  /**
   * Sets the value
   * @param val The value to set it to
   */
  void set(const T& val) { val_ = val; is_set_ = true; }

  /**
   * @return The value
   */
  T get() const { return val_; }

  /**
   * Clears the value
   */
  void clear() { val_ = T{}; is_set_ = false; }

  /**
   * @return Whether the value is set
   */
  bool empty() { return !is_set_; }

  /* Operators */

  Optional operator=(const T& val) {
    val_ = val;
    is_set_ = true;
    return *this;
  }

  operator T() const {
    return val_;
  }

  bool operator==(const bool& val) const {
    return (is_set_ == val);
  }

  explicit operator bool() const { return is_set_; }

 private:
  T val_{};
  bool is_set_ = false;
};
```

Comment: This isn't nearly what `std::optional` does. Your implementation only works for default constructible types `T`. This also initialises `T`whenever an optional is instantiated. The trick is to use a raw memory buffer with a placement-new. And your `get()` function should at least return a const reference. If you add some `std::move`-construction support it looks good otherwise! Keep it on!

Comment: I don't understand  the semantics of your equality comparison operator: `return (is_set_ == val);` doesn't make much sense for me. If both are set, shouldn't  that operation test for the equality of  `val_ == val.val_`? Can you elaborate about that please? In general I have to agree with @Maikel's comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The boolean operator is to check whether it has been set, not about the actual value. `if (optional )/if (optional == true)` would be it's usage. If you want to check the actual values you could do `if (optional.get() == other_val)`

Comment: @Lunatoid As mentioned that semantic is weird and unexpected, you already have an explicit type conversion operator to `bool`. At least with a `Optional<bool>` that would get extremely confusing.

Comment: @Lunatoid See also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp) please.

Comment: @Lunatoid You could give us some examples about the actually intended use. So we could give you some critiques about the API design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Prefer value type semantic**

Try to make classes default constructible and equality comparable whenever this makes sense. Currently your `Optional` class doesn't fulfil neither. The following code will not compile

```
class A { int a; A() = delete; };

int main()
{
  Optional<A> i;
}
```

Even though it might make sense to have an optional. Also consider this example

```
struct B { B() { /* insert something super long */ } }:

int main()
{
  Optional<B> opt_b; // this line takes really long!
}
```

[Here is an example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) of how to use `std::aligned_storage` to use uninitialised memory. I think this could help you as well.

**Do not return by value if you can**

The line

```
T get() const { return val_; }
```

Makes a copy of `T` while returning `val_`. Imagine val_ is a very big `std::string`. This could be very expensive in code which calls `get()` multiple times. If you want read-only access, prefer to use

```
const T& get() const& noexcept { return val_; }
```

instead.

**Make use of move assignments**

Currently you have to copy values into your optional. But what, if you just want to move something big that you want to return from a function? You 
need to add constructors for rvalue-`T`s.

```
Optional(T&& value)
 : val_{std::move(value)}
 , is_set_{true} {}
```

Comment: A few questions arose.
In the function declaration of `get` you changed `const` to `const&`, does that do anything significant?
And what is the use for noexcept? Why would it throw any exceptions and if so, why would I want to ignore them?

Comment: @Lunatoid They are called ref-qualifiers for member functions https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/ and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions

Comment: @Lunatoid `noexcept` is a contract with the compiler. It is used to tell it, that there won't be a exception and it does not have to prepare any stack unrolling. Since we only return a reference and do not copy anything it is unconditionally true, that no exception is going to happen. Like ref-qualifiers, `noexcept` is a C++11 feature too.

Comment: `const T& get() const& noexcept` means essentially: this is only usable in lvalue expressions and never throws (if it does, the program will terminate).

Comment: @Maikel I believe there are many more points to discuss about. For me it looks the OP completely screwed that at the semantical level. Nevertheless I upvoted your answer, for pointing out some of the basic flaws.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe its a self-thought programming exercise which is really hard to get "correct". The OP obviously decided for a different design. i.e. `set` function over an assignment operator and such. But it is true: when adding equality comparison one also has to drop `operator==(bool)`

Answer (score 3):

Maikel covered some issues, but since title says "reinventing *std::optional*", I'll assume that you want full blown [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (which is quite hard to get right, but not as hard as [std::variant](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141004/custom-basic-stdvariant)). I want to add that your code as it stands probably is good for your needs already. I'll also try to answer some of the questions you mentioned in the comments.

**edit:** [@L.F.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/188857/l-f) noticed that placement new is not `constexpr` friendly. For possibilities of getting that feature please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53084703/4593721) and it's accepted answer.

**Container:**

Currently value is stored in the variable of its own type. To make it more robust (such as handling non default constructible types, or types that are expensive to construct), it is possible to store the value in the byte array. Yes, it might sound scary, but it is the easiest approach in my opinion.

```
using byte = unsigned char;
alignas(T) byte[sizeof(T)] container;
```

Then it is possible to use [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to construct the value. Now we control when object will be constructed.

To access the value already stored in it, `reinterpret_cast<>` is needed. I know this starts sounding dangerous, but it is the way it should be.

```
T& get() noexcept
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&container[0]);
}

const T& get() const noexcept
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&container[0]);
}
```

The destructor will need to be changed then:

```
~Optional()
{
    reinterpret_cast<T*>(&container[0])->~T();
}
```

**noexcept**

`noexcept` means that the function promises that it won't throw, and if it will, `std::terminate` is called. It is good because people will know that they can call the function without worrying that it will throw. For example, they could use it in destructors, exception handlers, where throwing again would call `std::terminate`.

As a side note, if there is any member variable that has throwing destructor, the destructor of the enclosing class will be marked as `noexcept(false)` ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), see the explanation part), which might get into trouble in generic code.

**emplace construction:**

With current interface users will have to *construct the value and then copy it into the optional*, which is wasteful. One way is to create move constructor, the other way is to create conversion constructor (there is no real agreement on how those are called).

```
template <typename ... ArgTypes>
Optional(std::in_place_t<T>, ArgTypes ... args)
{
    new (&container[0]) T(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);  
}
```

Notice how I used `std::in_place_t<T>`. It is there because compiler will treat every call to constructor as conversion constructor. The reason is that `ArgTypes...` can be anything, which includes `bool`, `int`, `SomeTypeThatHasNothingToDoAboutIt` and `Optional<T>&`. `std::in_place_t<T>` will disambiguate that. As an example:

```
Optional<int> opt(2);
Optional<int> anotherOpt(opt); 
//                       ^^ ArgTypes is T&, not const T&,
//                        so conversion constructor will be called
//                        which is plain wrong.
```

The way to work around that would be:

```
Optional<int> anotherOpt(std::as_const(opt));
```

But it is almost the same typing as `std::in_place_t<T>`.

**assignment:**

The class would benefit from implementing `operator=(...)`. Move assigning would also be great. Additionally, there is no way to assign one `Optional` to another `Optional`, which would be great to have.

Comment: `optional` actually can't use explicit construction and destruction because of `constexpr` ...  It has to use union instead

Comment: @L.F., thanks for noticing that. Unfortunately I'm no longer on top of my game in terms of C++ rules, and have little time due to multiple jobs. I added a link to a SO that seems highly relevant and in line with what you said. Is there anything else I could improve?

Comment: Looks nice.  Actually I always assumed that placement new is *the* way to go, until I start to [implement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/225642) it, when I notice that placement new won't work in constexpr ...  Fortunately C++20 is gonna change this :)